# Is there a way to link checkboxes with parents in html without any javascript?

Tags: html, user-interface, checkbox

I know with checkboxes you can have an `indeterminate` state which has a dash or square dot in it. This is to tell the user it's children checkboxes have some but not 0 or all, selected. Is there a way to link children with parent checkboxes, so the state of the parent will automatically reflect the state of it's children, without javascript? Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="parent1"/> Parent 1
    <input type="checkbox" for="parent1"/> Child 1
    <input type="checkbox" for="parent1"/> Child 2
<input type="checkbox" name="parent2"/> Parent 2
    <input type="checkbox" for="parent2"/> Child 1
    <input type="checkbox" for="parent2"/> Child 2
```

Thanks

Comment: nope, you cannot link/nest checkboxes. You can't even set the `indeterminate` state without js.